# Interpolating Python version into here doc

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
cat <<EOF
System python : `python -V`
EOF
```

Its displaying as the following

`Python 2.6.6
System python :`

I want it to be shown this way

`System python : Python 2.6.6`

Comment: This is most useless use of cat I've ever seen! Use echo for this: ``echo 'System python :' `python -V 2>&1` ``

Comment: @myaut Maybe this is just part of a longer here-doc that he didn't bother showing because the rest is irrelevant.

Comment: @Barmar: than OP should mention that in his question.

Comment: Why? He wasn't asking a question about whether the here-doc is needed. Examples are supposed to be as short as possible to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @myaut this is just a small part of the here-doc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using backticks is [not recommended](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) anymore; better use `$()`:

```
VERSION=$(python -V 2>&1)
echo "System python : $VERSION"
```

(as noted by many other comments; I redirect the stderr output to stdout; since python -V prints to stderr)

Comment: @anon than you can gain from this: "Nested quoting inside $() is far more convenient." `echo "System python : $(python -V 2>&1)"`

Comment: Thanks mate , i was missing 2>&1 when i tried `${}`

Answer (score 2):

Python is sending the version information to `stderr` instead of `stdout`. So it's being printed immediately when you run the `python -v` command, rather than being included in the expansion of the command. Redirect its `stderr` to `stdout` to solve this:

```
cat <<EOF
System python : `python -V 2>&1`
EOF
```

Comment: Note that, as of Python 3.4, the output from `-V` now goes to `stdout` as one would expect.  https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#changes-in-python-command-behavior

Comment: But code that's checking the version number should try to be version-agnostic.

Comment: Yes, of course, and your solution is, although your answer doesn't mention it.  I was just noting for the record that Python's old behavior was counterintuitive and has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This will cover any spacing issues

```
alpha=$(python -V 2>&1)
echo "System python : $alpha"
```

[Why `$()` is preferred](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)

Answer (score 0):

This is most useless use of cat I've ever seen!

Use echo for this:

```
echo 'System python :' `python -V 2>&1`
```

To clarify: `python -V` outputs data to stderr, so it is not captured by shell and printed immediately. `2>&1` redirects stderr to stdout, so everything working fine.